# Stop replacing my tabs with four spaces

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined

## Typing Literal Tab Characters

I do not know how feasible this is, for the developers, but I do believe, that at least on this site, it may make more sense to stop expanding tabs into four spaces.

If the browser side code can be made to render tabs as four spaces, this issue is moot. Some code golf answers (or input samples) require a literal tab in the source and there should be a way to indicate that.

I am not a web developer, so I may be clueless, but I will put this up for a feature request and take any <s>flak</s> downvotes.

---

This is not intended to incite any tabs versus space wars.

---

Wow! This post seems to have garnered a significant community consensus. As such, I have put this up for a network wide feature request [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285838/expansion-of-tabs)!

Comment: Code golf or not, whitespace is significant in some languages (notably Python), and replacing tabs with spaces could.break the code. If we *can* get a site-specific exception for this, it should apply to *all* control characters (with the obvious exception of NUL).

Comment: Yes, this is a fantastic idea! I also am not a Web Dev, but dear SE, can we please see unprintable characters too?

Comment: this would probably be a fairly easy userscript to write, i can look into it later if i'm not busy. it would replace *any* set of four continuous spaces though, which would break at least one of my answers on this site, but the spaces/tabs issue is far more pressing

Comment: alternatively i could make it work only at the start of a line, but that wouldn't cover every case and also would still break stuff (very very very long python code, for example) but it would be much rarer. i don't know which would be better

Comment: AFAIK this can be quite a problem for Python answers which mix tabs and spaces for saving bytes

Comment: @Dennis Why not NUL?

Comment: @jimmy23013 A literal NUL is a parse error, but I'm not sure about escapes. It can create problems for copy-pasting though.

Comment: Given the Python requirements, it seems like this might be an issue for Code Review as well. I see [this thread](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/40643) discussing a bookmarklet workaround, but my minimal searching hasn't yielded anything else.

Comment: @undergroundmonorail I'm afraid there is no userscript which can be made, because the tabs are gone server-side :(

Comment: @EriktheGolfer yeah, but 4 spaces in a row are pretty uncommon so you can just convert that to tabs and it's probably good enough

Comment: @undergroundmonorail Poor [Whitespace](//esolangs.org/wiki/whitespace)...

Comment: @EriktheGolfer it's not like the current solution is good for whitespace

Comment: @undergroundmonorail You are definitely making it worse, because not only Whitespace, but other languages who need four spaces somewhere (say, a string), can't be added, while many languages support `\t` in strings instead of a tab character. For example, to print a hollow 6x6 square, you need at least one occurence of four spaces (inside the square), which not many languages support as `\s`, and is too impractical and non-golfy at all to do something like `print'|%s|'%' '*4`. Also, take COBOL as an example; it *needs* to have *7* spaces in front of every code line, not a tab and 3 spaces.

Comment: @EriktheGolfer I'm adding to my [previous comment](/q/10024?noredirect=1#comment32034_10024) that any programs which try to restore the original four spaces will fail, because it's indistinguishable whether a tab was four spaces or really a tab.

Comment: We could always scrape the post source...

Comment: Could we please get an official response on this? Is there a protocol to directly reach out to a community dev and get this either approved or rejected?

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala Unfortunately there is not. You could post a feature request on meta.se and link them back here.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I'm pretty sure that tabs and other unprintables are never even stored server-side.

Comment: Perhaps should we ask for an "upload" button so we can send the code via a file and have it displayed.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem I will attempt that if this continues for a bit more with no official response. The more upvotes I show when I take to mother meta, the better. Conversely if there is some dissent to this idea, I wish to give an opportunity for someone to downvote and/or commentabout why this is not a good idea.

Comment: If that's the case, someone should write up an answer here covering the points made in comments.

Comment: @Geobits should I take this to mother meta? I feel that 46 upvotes and no downvotes is a fair consensus to show to mother meta.

Comment: Sure, but I'd still write up an answer so that when you link back here it's summarized.

Answer (score 7):

> As per this feature request: [Stop expanding tabs into four spaces](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285838/)
>
> `&#9;`
>
> Note that this only works if you put the code within a `<pre><code>` block, which means you also have to escape `<` with `&lt;` (and `&` with `&amp;` in certain cases), so it's still annoying, but if you do a find/replace on your code, you can make it work.
>
> If you really need to display tabs correctly, this workaround helps.

Comment: It has been decided that this workaround will be the only way because the feature request was declined.